# Two number theory questions: primes of the form $a^m+1$ and $2^{2^k}+5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that if $a$ is a positive integer and $a^m+1$ is an odd prime, then $m=2^n$ for some nonnegative integer $n$.

I followed the hint given in the book and rewrote it like this:

Let $a^m+1=(a^k+1)(a^{k(l-1)}-a^{k(l-2)}+\cdots-a^{k}+1)$ where $m=kl$ and $l$ is odd.  I understand why $a^k+1$ is greater than $1$.  However, I don't understand why $a^{k(l-1)}-a^{k(l-2)}+\cdots-a^{k}+1\neq 1.$  I understand that we are trying to show it has non-trivial factorization, but I don't understand why the second part has non-trivial factorization.

> Find all of the primes of the form $2^{2^n}+5$, where $n$ is a nonnegative integer.

For this question I'm stuck trying to understand why its important to discuss this in terms of $3k+1$ and $3k+2$.  I am also aware the only prime in this form is $7$.

Comment: If the second factor is 1, then $a^m+1=a^k+1$.

Comment: $2^{2r}\equiv1\pmod3$.

Comment: Dead Homer provided almost a complete solution. However, you still have a reasonable doubt regarding his solution which is valid. I would explain the part 1 of your question as,$a^m+1=(a^k+1)(a^{k(l-1)}-a^{k(l-2)}+\cdots-a^k+1)$.Now,observe that the signs are alternating,so since $a$ is a natural number,and m too,so $a^{k(l-1)}>a^{k(l-2)}$ and if the number of terms in the $a$ exponent are odd, so it obviously ends with a "$+$".

Answer (score 1):

1)  If $a^{k(l−1)}−a^{k(l−2)}+⋯−a^k+1=1$ then we would have $a^m+1 = a^k+1$.  This can only happen if $a=1$ or $m=k$.  But $a=1 \implies a^m+1=2$, a contradiction since 2 is not an odd prime.  Therefore, $m=k$, i.e., $l=1$.  So, the only odd factor of $m$ is 1.  Therefore, $m$ is a power of 2.

2)  $2 \equiv -1 \mod 3$.  If $n>0$, then $2^n$ is even.  Therefore, $2^{2^n} \equiv (-1)^{2^n} \equiv 1 \mod 3$.  So, $2^{2^n} + 5 \equiv 0 \mod 3$.  This shows that if $n>0$ then $2^{2^n}+5$ is divisible by 3 and so is not prime.  On the other hand, if $n=0$, then $2^{2^n}+5=7$, which is prime.

Comment: The only thing I don't follow is why $l$ is the only odd factor.  All I know is that $l$ is some odd number.

Comment: If $m=kl$ and $m=k$ then $l=1$, i.e., 1 is the only possible odd factor.

Comment: Right, so how does this force $m$ to be a power of $2$.

Comment: What are the possible factors of $m$?

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking about this incorrectly.  Where I'm stuck is what if $k$ were odd.  Then $m=kl=(2j+1)\cdot 1.$